# How to get mesibo message reply name

Tags: kotlin, mesibo

I tried to revamp mesibo reply message and have problem when getting the person name, this is the code I use
[image]
I use repliedToMessage to get reply information, but give wrong person name, for example I reply my message but the profile name I got from repliedToMessage return opposite person name
[image]

How to determine the reply person name, it's reply from own or opposite message?

Update :
i change the code to mesibo suggested answer
[image]

it works for personal profile message, but still have a problem in group message

[image]

in group profile reply name still show self profile name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile is always for the peer. To display the proper name, you need to check if the replied message is incoming or outgoing.

You can call `isIncoming()` or `isOutgoing()` on the MesiboMessage object returned by `repliedToMessage()` to determine the direction.

For example:

```
MesiboMessage rm = msg.getRepliedToMessage();

if(rm.isIncoming()) {

    // display name from the profile

} else if(rm.isOutgoing()) {

    // display name from self profile
}
```

Please refer to the example in the following documentation:

https://docs.mesibo.com/tutorials/get-started/sending-and-receiving-messages/#receiving-messages-message-status-and-updates

Comment: it works for personal chat but it still has a problem in group message, please see the updated question

Comment: Why are you displaying the profile name for outgoing messages? It should be for incoming messages as answered.